# Running perl command from scala process

Tags: regex, scala, command, system

I have to make this command run from my scala code

```
perl -ne '/pattern/ && print $1 and last' filename
```

I have tried

```
val re = """pattern"""
 val file = "filename"
 val v= (Process(Seq("""perl -ne '/"""+re+"""/ && print $1 and last' """+file))).!!
```

But some how despite generating the same command required for command line its still not working.It says:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "perl -ne '/pattern/ && print $1 and last' file": error=2, No such file or directory.

Can anyone suggest where its going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this?

```
 val pattern: String = "..." // your pattern
 val perlCode = s""" '/$pattern/ && print $$1 and last' """
 val v = (Process(Seq("perl", "-ne", perlCode, file))).!!
```

The issue is `Process` takes a `Seq`uence of arguments that will be executed. In your case,
`perl -ne '/pattern/ && print $1 and last' filename`

`perl` is the first, `-ne` the second, followed by the perl code `/pattern/ && print $1 and last` (note that the single quotes `'` are not relevant, they are just used to ensure that the string of code is passed as a single argument to `perl`) and last you have the filename.

The [scala.sys.process docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.package) show you pretty much everything. If your file is an `java.io.File`, try:

```
 val perlCmd = Seq("perl", "-ne", perlCode)
 val file = new java.io.File("/tmp/f.txt")
 val result = perlCmd #< file !!
```

Which is the same as

```
perl -ne '/pattern/ && print $1 and last' < /tmp.txt
```

Comment: what if instead of file as a string I use file as java.io.File? How will the code change then?